# ClearButton in react-bootstrap-typeahead with 2 X superimposed

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have a graphical bug with the ClearButton provided by react-bootstrap-typeahead. I wanted to replace it with another button (for instance the CloseButton from Bootstrap). Unfortunately, the CloseButton is not clickable.

Graphical bug

[image: 1]

What do I do wrong ?

```
import { CloseButton } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Typeahead, ClearButton } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css";
<Typeahead
      id="search"
      options={chartData.datasets}
      labelKey={chartData.datasets.label}
      placeholder="look for projects"
      multiple
      onChange={setMultiSelections}
      selected={multiSelections}
    >
      {({ onClear, selected }) => (
        <div className="rbt-aux">
          {!!selected.length && <CloseButton onClick={onClear} />}
        </div>
      )}
</Typeahead>
```

- try to change `rbt-close-content` css class
- I used `react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.bs5.css` instead.

Comment: What versions of bootstrap, react-bootstrap, and react-bootstrap-typeahead are you using?

Comment: Hey Ericgio, thanks for your help :) 

 `"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.0.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^6.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there may be two different issues here:

**1. The clear button isn't clickable.**

This is happening because `.rbt-aux` has `pointer-events: none;` set to avoid blocking clicks on the input. The default close button then has `pointer-events: auto;` to enable clicks on the button. You'll need to add something similar, or define your own element to position the clear button that doesn't remove pointer-events.

```
.rbt-aux .btn-close {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

**2. There are two instances of the clear button being rendered in the component.**

I'm not sure why this is happening. Based on your code sample, there should only be one button rendering. If you plan on rendering a custom clear button, be sure not to set the `clearButton` prop on the typeahead (or set it to `false`, which is the default).

Comment: Works fine :). Thank you very much for your help ericgio, great work !